# Titan on AWS- Prevent dropping of edges and vertex's

Tags: amazon-web-services, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Is there a way to run a gremlin server so that the drop command is prevented? I never actually drop any edges or vertex's so I'd like the added assurance that it can't be done by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have some luck developing your own TraversalStrategy and intercept the behavior of the `.drop()` step, preventing it to actually delete data. However, people could still be able to bypass the Gremlin/TinkerPop API and directly manipulate the `graph` instance and remove graph elements (`Vertex`, `Edge` and `Property`).

Depending on your use case, you might just want to disable any mutation to the graph, and not just the removal of elements:

- At the Titan level, you can use the `storage-read.only` option which makes the Titan storage backend read only. See [Titan v1.0.0 documentation, Ch. 12 - Configuration reference, 12.3.23. storage](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-config-ref.html#_storage).
- You can also handle this at the TinkerPop level with the `ReadOnlyStrategy` Traversal strategy. See [TinkerPop v3.0.1 documentation on ReadOnlyStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_readonlystrategy).